# What Star Trek TOS characters have been confirmed to be appearing in Discovery?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-the-original-series, star-trek-discovery

Since the new Star Trek: Discovery series is set 10 years before the events of The Original Series, are there any characters from the original *Star Trek* series that have been confirmed will appear in Discovery?

Also, who will be playing these characters?

Comment: Short answer, we don't know.  Very little information has been given, and if something like that was to occur, it'd probably be a one-off episode.  Aside from Sarek, it's not known.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there are a couple that I know of (now that we are closer to airing)...

**~~~Spoiler Warning~~~~**

[image: Sarek - CBS ALL ACCESS]

James Frain will be playing **Sarek**--He is VERY important to the main character, Michael's (Soniqua Martin) story -- and Rainn Wilson is playing **Harry Mudd**.

But on the whole *Discovery* advertises **new heroes and villains** and is exploring 24 Klingon Houses to expand on different cultures on different planets. In addition Michael is not the Captain of any ship, but the series is going to be from her perspective.

http://variety.com/2017/tv/news/star-trek-discovery-rainn-wilson-harry-mudd-1202019986/

**UPDATE: Season 2 Casting Spoilers Ahead!**

> Ason Mount has been tapped to play USS Enterprise's **Captain Pike**.
>  He has a mission enacted through Discovery, which includes a search
>  for **Spock** played by Gregory Peck's grandson, Ethan Peck. In
>  addition a **character** originally featured in the original series'
>  pilot, Pike's **"Number One"**, but was then taken out by a bad reaction from the test audience, is now
>  re-instated back into canon and played by Rebecca Romijn. It is also
>  presumed from the [trailers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x6eoD9rQHL4) and/or possibly Star Trek Discovery's
>  [Short Treks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lDPPTFKNFtY) that **Harry Mudd**, **Amanda Greyson**, and
>  **Serak** will also return in some capacity.